# WPF canvas VisibilityChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, canvas, event-handling

I want to set up an event to run when the `Visibility` is changed on a WPF `Canvas` control.

```
canvas1.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(canvas1_VisibleChanged);
```

I have tried the above but it doesn't work, anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for the `IsVisibleChanged` event, which applies to ALL UIElements:

[UIElement.IsVisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx)

---

More Information: `IsVisible` is a read-only Dependency Property. It is a calculated value, and the `Visibility` Dependency Property affects it. This is what you should use to detect if you're `UIElement` is visible or not.

Now, if you really really wanna just check for the `Visibility` DP changing for whatever reason there is a way to do so: http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/

Though, I'd still stick with just tracking the `IsVisibleChanged`.

Answer (score -1):

The normal WPF Canvas object does not have a .VisibleChanged event, so you can't assign an event handler to it.